# Why doesn't Jenkins build with new changes?

Tags: jenkins

We have something very strange on jenkins.

If we commit some codes, Jenkins will notice that the changes are there and the build will be triggered. But it builds with OLDER CODES, not the new ones!

How could it happen? Did we configure something wrong?

As source control we use git. Jenkins knows the repository and if there is something changed in the repository, jenkins starts to build.

Our build configuration is like this:

```
Build:
Maven: 3.04
Stamm-Pom: pom.xml
Goals and Options: -e -s ./settings.xml -Pdev clean wildfly:deploy
```

And we don't have any pre-build steps.

Comment: You make no mention of the source control you are using.  And, have you checked the console output for the job?

Comment: To determine if you have configured something wrong it would be helpful to know what you have configured at all...

Comment: @rrirower Thanks for your comment, the question was edited just now.

Comment: @UweAllner Thanks for your comment, the question was edited just now.

Comment: Your console output should indicate what version of the source is being used for the build.  Have you checked the console output?

Comment: @rrirower i checked that the version is correct. But thanks for mentioning "source control" by you just now. I checked our repository and we commited the Caches! I think it should be the reason why it is not working correctly:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We commited caches into the source control repository. And we only use wildfly:deploy to build, then the caches are used. We just need to delete the caches and add lines in ".gitignore" to ignore the caches, so that the caches are not commited any more.